# Which web frameworks support Python3 (PEP3333 - WSGI 1.0.1 compliance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi, web-frameworks

I had recently started learning Python, and with all the research I decided it was good to start with Python3 (that's what even Guido advised at Google IO'11). But lack of support for Python3 by major (web)frameworks has really bugged me. I know this same question has been asked all over the Internet and even on StackOverflow, but since we now have a finalized [PEP3333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/) (WSGI 1.0.1), which are the frameworks supporting/going-to-support Py3. The only one I could find was [CherryPy3.2.0](http://www.cherrypy.org/) which, as the project page says, is PEP 3333 compliant. I specially would like to know about Django/Turbogears/Pylons/Flask (Any roadmaps would be really informative).

Comment: I went through the same process. After a few days I decided to use whatever version of python that came with my system (python 2.6). I found this much better since all of the stuff that's out there already works which accelerated my learning process.

Comment: Btw, that's what I have done now. I am working on Python2.6 and Django 1.3. I will looking out for any Py3 support that comes and update this question when possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was earlier little incentive for web frameworks to move to Python 3, as there was no usable WSGI standard for Python 3. Now we have PEP 3333, but it is still very new, so few frameworks had yet had time to port to Python 3.

Besides CherryPy there is only two other Python 3 web frameworks I'm aware of, and that is [QP](http://www.mems-exchange.org/software/qp/), which seems very different from other frameworks and to my knowledge doesn't use WSGI at all, and [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/), which claims to support PEP 3333 (although you have to dig a bit in the docs to find it).

Django has no official roadmap for Python 3 AFAIK (except an old one that is outdated by now), but there has been promises to work on it during the summer.

Pyramid is waiting for the component architecture to get ported, and I that's mostly been done by me so far, and I don't have time at the moment. :-) I don't know if there is a roadmap for Pyramid, but there is one for the component architecture. There is no timeline, though, as it depends wholly on the time of volunteers.

In general, although Guido is sensible in recommending Python 3, that doesn't really work for web programming today.

Comment: If I am not wrong, Pyramid is sort of a merge of TurboGears and Pylons project, right?

Comment: @pcxor: It is a merge of Pylons and BFG.  See http://bfg.repoze.org/ and http://docs.pylonsproject.org/faq/pyramid.html

Comment: Experimental support for Python 3 is available in Django 1.5, with 1.6 offering complete support; as per the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/).

Answer (score 3):

[EDIT]
Official Django Project roadmap regarding Python 3 [here](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/mar/13/py3k/)

the current Django trunk (r17165) ([link here](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/)) clears Py3 tests ([Google Group 
dicsussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/XjrX3FIPT-U))! Django on Py3, finally!!